# Can only access IP addresses

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, redhat

I just inherited a RHEL 4.1 minimal image server and am trying to set it up but I can only seem to access ip addresses and not domain names.  (exmaple: wget google.com doesn't work, wget 67.222.5.136 does though).

How can I fix this -- this is preventing me from using yum/rpm etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add your DNS addresses to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
nameserver <address of DNS1>
nameserver <address of DNS2>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you get you network configuration with DHCP, check in the file `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf` that you have the following statement :

```
request domain-name-servers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the /etc/resolv.conf file to determine the DNS servers
like this :

```
nameserver <server dns 1>
nameserver <server dns 2>
```

If you dont know what dns to use, here an example with opendns servers

```
cat >> /etc/resov.conf
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some DNS servers to your IP config.  You can do this by firing up your favourite editor and adding the following to /etc/resolv.conf :

```
nameserver <ip of primary DNS server>
nameserver <ip of secondary DNS server>
```

Alternatively, if you use DHCP to get your IP addresses, make sure that the DHCP server is actually configured to give out Name Servers and then check dhclient.conf (usually /etc/dhcp*x*/dhclient.conf) includes the following:

```
request domain-name-servers;
```